# SQL - LEFT JOIN with Condition

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM "Table 1" T1
LEFT JOIN "Table 2" T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T2."Status" <> 'Void'
```

SQL: MYSQL

Hi all,

Above is my attempt so far, but it's not filtering the Void columns.

I need all the columns in Table 1 to remain, except if the "Status" column in Table 2 contains 'Void'.

Thanks,

Comment: Try this     SELECT T1.Cols,  T2.Status
    FROM "Table 1" T1
    LEFT JOIN "Table 2" T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    WHERE

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following solution to see if it works.
Here I put filtering Table 2's status on the joint statement

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `Table 1` T1
LEFT JOIN `Table 2` T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND T2.`Status` <> 'Void'
```